# Clustering evaluation measure for overlapping clustering

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, evaluation

I am doing research on clustering evaluation measures in overlapping subspaces clusters. However, I still haven't found something that really helps me to measure the quality of a clustering. So far what I have seen most appropriate to me would be to use the Jaccard index. The figure below shows an example of what I get with overlapping subspace clustering.

**Expected result for the clustering.**
[image: reference]

As you can see, I can see overlap in rows and columns. So, if I use traditional measures (for example ARI, Silhouette, DB) I don't capture the quality taking into account the overlap. Has anyone studied anything in this regard? Sorry if I missed any presentation rules, this is my first time interacting here.

Comment: What exactly do you want to evaluate? What is the problem with existing measures? Where and how do they fail for your example data? What would you like to get instead? Also please note, that this site is more for practical programming problems. I think that there are dedicated sites for computer science problems on the network. It might still be ontopic though.

Comment: To be more precise, I don't understand what you mean by "they don't capture the quality taking into account the overlap". Maybe one could be more explicit there.

Comment: Hi @Trilarion. I want to evaluate the clustering result, e.g, clustering X is better than Y? So, we can use ARI, Silhouette, or other measures to evaluate the result in an objective way. However, such measures are well when the object does not overlap because each object belongs to only one cluster. So, as we can see in the figure, an object can belong to more than one cluster. I remembered the fuzzy clustering methods and now I will see what strategy it was used. Sorry if I go out of the site purpose. If you have any recommendations for an appropriate site I will appreciate your tip.

Comment: There are some stackexchange sites where I think this question might be ontopic. The scope of the sites overlaps. Possibilities apart from this would be https://dsp.stackexchange.com/, https://datascience.stackexchange.com/, https://stats.stackexchange.com/ or https://cs.stackexchange.com/, I think, but check with them first.

Comment: Tkx, @Trilarion! I will check it out.